# NaN after adding particular key element in an Array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, arrayobject

I have an Array object with 3000 objects. Among these 3000 few of them have grade and few object doesn't. Now I want to sum the grades. I'm getting NaN. Could you please guide me what am I doing wrong. Below is the sample code:

```js
const arr=[
{
"name":"Harvey",
"grade":3
},
{
"name":"Pamela",
},
{
"name":"Scott",
"grade":4
},
{
"name":"Joshua",
"grade":5
},{
"name":"Rachel",
},{
"name":"Harvey",
"grade":3
},
]

let classTotal = arr.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
     return { 
       grade:  (previousValue.grade + currentValue.grade)
   }
   })
console.log(classTotal) //NaN
```

Also tried the following:

```
let classTotal=arr.reduce((accum, item) => accum + item.total, 0)
console.log(classTotal) // Same NaN
```

Comment: zerro in the end means initial counter value, then when you add grade to grade you have to use ((previousValue.grade || 0) + (currentValue.grade || 0))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NaN is "Not a valid Number" you have some entries missing `grade` you should run `filter` to filter them out before your reduce

```js
const arr = [{
    "name": "Harvey",
    "grade": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Pamela",
  },
  {
    "name": "Scott",
    "grade": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "Joshua",
    "grade": 5
  }, {
    "name": "Rachel",
  }, {
    "name": "Harvey",
    "grade": 3
  },
]

let classTotal = arr.filter(function(element) {
  return element.grade
}).reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
  return {
    grade: (previousValue.grade + currentValue.grade)
  }
})

console.log(classTotal)
```

Or, you can add a `0` for example for the elements who does not have a grade:

```js
const arr = [{
    "name": "Harvey",
    "grade": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Pamela",
  },
  {
    "name": "Scott",
    "grade": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "Joshua",
    "grade": 5
  }, {
    "name": "Rachel",
  }, {
    "name": "Harvey",
    "grade": 3
  },
]

let classTotal = arr.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
  return {
    grade: (previousValue.grade + (currentValue.grade || 0))
  }
})

console.log(classTotal)
```

Answer (score 3):

If either of the `.grade` values is itself not a number (such as `undefined`) then it will break the ongoing calculations.  One approach could be to default it to `0` when no value is present.  So instead of `currentValue.grade` you might use `(currentValue.grade ?? 0)`.  For example:

```js
const arr=[
  {
    "name":"Harvey",
    "grade":3
  },
  {
    "name":"Pamela",
  },
  {
    "name":"Scott",
    "grade":4
  },
  {
    "name":"Joshua",
    "grade":5
  },
  {
    "name":"Rachel",
  },
  {
    "name":"Harvey",
    "grade":3
  },
];

let classTotal = arr.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
  return { 
    grade: (previousValue.grade + (currentValue.grade ?? 0))
  };
});
console.log(classTotal);
```